What portion of the area of the parallelogram is the area of the figure bounded by these lines?

I encountered this problem: Each vertex of a parallelogram is connected with the midpoints of two opposite sides by straight lines. What portion of the area of the parallelogram is the area of the figure bounded by these lines?

I was able to prove that the shaded area is $\frac 1 6$ of the area of the parallelogram, but my solution involved dividing the parallelogram from line $GH$ and calculating the area of each triangle within the shape.

These portions are for this parallelogram (the lower half).
My question is: Is there easier ways to solve this problem ? I think there might be some trick that will solve this question without all of my calculations.

@Blue Heads up that it's not a regular octagon. The angles are not $135^\circ$.

@CalvinLin: Oops! Right you are. How embarrassing! I'll delete the comment.


Note that

Each "spiky" red triangle (with solid edges) has the same area as an adjacent "central" blue triangle, since they have equal bases and heights. The total red area equals the total blue area.

Each "outer" yellow triangle (with solid edges) is similar to a blue "central" triangle, with scale factor $2$. The total yellow area is $2^2$-times the total blue area.


We conclude that the area of the parallelogram is $6$-times that of the octagon.

I feel the same way as @Blue about the constant area ratio, so working in a square would make things easier. But when I obtained an apparently distant value of $\dfrac16$ for said proportion, I began to doubt who was right in this story. I came to the conclusion that both criteria are indeed true but that your value of $\dfrac16$ is approximate, not exact (I saw this when I confirmed that the true proportion is $\dfrac{72}{\sqrt{145}}=5.97927454947\approx 6$).
Calculations In the square of side $1$ with opposed vertices $(0,0)$ and $(1,1)$ we consider the three lines
$$y=2x\\y=-2x+1\\y=\frac{x+1}{2}$$ from which the two points $\left(\dfrac14,\dfrac12\right)$ and $\left(\dfrac13,\dfrac23\right)$ determining the side $\dfrac{\sqrt5}{12}$ of the resulting octagon.
The involved apotegma measure then $\dfrac{\sqrt{29}}{24}$ and the area of the octagon is $\dfrac{\sqrt{145}}{72}$.
Thus the proportion is $\dfrac{1}{\dfrac{\sqrt{145}}{72}} =\dfrac{72}{\sqrt{145}}$.
As said above this exact value is very close to $6$.

-1. Unfortunately, we do NOT have a regular octagon (unlike what Blue claimed). For example, the area of a regular octagon with side length $s$ is $ 2 ( 1+ \sqrt{2} ) s^2$, which contradicts the value that you found. $\quad$ In particular, the angle at $K$ is $ \pi - 2 \tan^{-1} \frac{1}{2}  \approx 127^\circ$ and not $135^\circ$.

You could fix this by showing that the distance from the center $(1/2, 1/2)$ to the line $ 2x - y = 0 $ is $ | \frac{ 2 (1/2) - 1(1/2) + 0 } { \sqrt{ 2^2 + (-1)^2 }} | = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{5} } $. Hence, the area of the octagon is $ 8 \times  \frac{1}{2} \times \frac{1}{2\sqrt{5} } \times \frac{ \sqrt{5}} { 12 }  =  \frac{1}{6} $ as desired.

Yeah ... I mistakenly claimed that the octagon is regular. (I think I intended merely "symmetric" but wrote "regular" out of force of habit. :) ... Anyway, I've posted an answer that doesn't bother transforming the parallelogram into a square.
